# What is the most efficient way to continuously make a request on server

Tags: android, http, android-service, httprequest

I have constructed a background service in which, every particular interval, a request to the server is made which - in successful cases - a JSON response is parsed.

I am using *Retrofit API* to handle this situation, but I have come to a point where I wonder if this is the most efficient solution.

Should I use **sockets** or some other kind of API? Is this memory efficient?

Comment: I would recommend websockets

Comment: You should try firebase

Comment: if this is going on forever, i mean even if app in background, then this is bad, it will drain battery and it's not good practice, u can use Push Notifications to notify the client that a new data is available, and only then the app requests update from server.

Comment: I already use Push Notifications but that is not my problem here. What practice is best to use?

Comment: my point is, if u r using push notification, then why do u want to continuously request a URL, u can make use of PN, on specific actions, the server sends a PN to the related devices, with a command ? (NEW_DATA_AVAILABLE) on mobile app if u get this message, u make the request, my whole point is not to keep requesting a url, unless this is really what you want and that's how ur app works.

Comment: I see..So how the server can know when to send this command?

Comment: it depends on the data you are trying to fetch with that request, if it's CHECK_NEW_ARTICLES for example, when the admin adds a new article, a PN should be sent to the users (clients) NEW_ARTICLE_ADDED so each client will get that new item with a request

Comment: Yeah, but I mean how to do it technically? I have to setup a server?

Comment: yes, it involves some server-side code, how much code and how, this depends on the way you want to use PN, as a sender, you may want to look for some tutorials or docs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Socket is the best way for continues connection or network calling, And also faster calling if you are using socket,

Also throw socket you can make like live connection, But for continues connection in background you need to create service and manage properly.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I see. Can you provide me a proper tutorial or a lib to start up with?

Answer (score 0):

Push mechanism is the most efficient way than Polling(network request to server in intervals), provided the server supports push mechanism.

You can refer this for GCM.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm

But in case if polling is the only way, you case use any of these

- Service
- Handler
- AlarmManager

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html